# what is the difference between dojoAttachpoint and id .

Tags: dojo

```
<div dojoType="dojo.Dialog" id="alarmCatDialog" bgColor="#FFFFFF" 
     bgOpacity="0.4" toggle="standard">
   <div class='dijitInline'>
       <input type='input' class='dateWidgetInput' 
        dojoAttachPoint='numberOfDateNode' selected="true" />
</div>
```

how to show this dialog I tried `dijit.byId('alarmCatDialog').show();`

The above code is a template and I called `dijit.byId('alarmCatDialog').show()` from the .js file .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between dojoAttachpoint and id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056858/difference-between-dojoattachpoint-and-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojoAttachPoint` is used in a template and can be accessed in the widget using the value of the attribute.

So if the html that you posted is used in a widget template, then you should use `dojoAttachPoint`.  In the js file for the widget:

```
dojo.declare("MyWidget", [dijit._Widget, dijit._Templated], {

  alarmCatDialog: null, // the dialog widget will be attached to this field.

  templateString: dojo.cache(...), 

  widgetsInTemplate: true,

  postCreate: function() {
    this.inherited(arguments);

    this.alarmCatDialog.show();
  }
});
```

You should not use id within widgets, because ids must be unique across all dom nodes.  Using it within a widgets limits the use of your widget to once on a page.

Also since you have widgets in your template, you should use `widgetsInTemplate: true`

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/_Templated.html#widgetsintemplate