# Difference between dojoAttachpoint and id

Tags: dojo

```
<div dojoType="dojo.Dialog" id="alarmCatDialog" bgColor="#FFFFFF" bgOpacity="0.4" toggle="standard">
<div class='dijitInline'>
       <input type='input' class='dateWidgetInput' dojoAttachPoint='numberOfDateNode' selected="true">
</div>
```

how to show this dialog I tried `dijit.byId('alarmCatDialog').show();`

The above code is a template and I called `dijit.byId('alarmCatDialog').show()` from the .js file .

`dojo.attr(this.numberOfDateNode)` this code works and I got the data .but if I change dojoattachpoint to id then I try `dijit.byId('numberOfDateNode')` will not work;

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the difference between dojoAttachpoint and id .](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056477/what-is-the-difference-between-dojoattachpoint-and-id)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your *numberOfDateNode* is a plain DOM node, not a widget/dijit, i.e. javascript object extending `dijit/_Widget`, which is the reason you cannot get a reference to it via `dijit.byId("numberOfDateNode")`. Use `dojo.byId("numberOfDateNode")` instead and you are all set.

`dojoAttachPoint` or its HTML5 valid version `data-dojo-attach-point` is being used inside a *dijit* template to *attach* a reference to DOM node or child dijit to dijit javascript object, which is the reason  `dijit.byId('alarmCatDialog').numberOfDateNode` has a reference to your `<input type='input' class='dateWidgetInput' .../>`.

The main reason to use `data-dojo-attach-point` is that:

- you can create multiple instances of *dijit* and therefore your template cannot identify nodes/dijits by IDs as you will have multiple nodes/dijits with the same ID
- it's an elegant declarative way, so your code won't be full of `dijit.byId/dojo.byId`.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to keep track of what is the *contents* and which is the *template* of the dijit.Dialog. Once you set contents of a dialog, its markup is parsed - but not in a manner, such that the TemplatedMixin is applied to the content-markup-declared-widgets.

To successfully implement a template, you would need something similar to the following code, note that I've commented where attachPoints kicks in.

[This SitePen blog](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/24/creating-dojo-widgets-with-inline-templates/) renders nice info on the subject

```
define(
 [
   "dojo/declare",
    "dojo/_base/lang",
    "dijit/_Templated",
   "dijit/_Widget",
   "dijit/Dialog"
 ], function(
   declare,
    lang,
    _Templated,
    _Widget,
   Dialog
 ) {
  return declare("my.Dialog", [Dialog, _Templated], {
      // set any widget (Dialog construct) default parameters here
       toggle: 'standard',
        // render the dijit over a specific template
        // you should be aware, that once this templateString is overloaded,
        // then the one within Dialog is not rendered
      templateString: '<div bgColor="#FFFFFF" bgOpacity="0.4">' +// our domNode reference
                '<div class="dijitInline">' +
                    // setting a dojoAttachPoint makes it referencable from within widget by this attribute's value
                '  <input type="input" class="dateWidgetInput" dojoAttachPoint="numberOfDateNode" selected="true">' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>',

        constructor: function(args, srcNodeRef) {
            args = args || {} // assert, we must mixin minimum an empty object
            lang.mixin(this, args);
        },
        postCreate: function() {

                    // with most overrides, preferred way is to call super functionality first
                    this.inherited(arguments);

            // here we can manipulate the contents of our widget, 
            // template parser _has run from this point forward
            var input = this.numberOfDateNode;
            // say we want to perform something on the numberOfDateNode, do so

        },
        // say we want to use dojo.Stateful pattern such that a call like
        //   myDialogInstance.set("dateValue", 1234)
        // will automatically set the input.value, do as follows
        _setDateValueAttr: function(val) {
            // NB: USING dojoAttachPoint REFERENCE
            this.numberOfDateNode.value = val;
        },
        // and in turn we must set up the getter
        _getDateValueAttr: function() {
            // NB: USING dojoAttachPoint REFERENCE
            return this.numberOfDateNode.value;
        }

  });

});
```